# Operation of a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

***Background:***

I am trying to figure out how a MOSFET operates for a college project. From what I know, it operates similarly to a BJT except for the following:

- MOSFETs are voltage-controlled.
- MOSFETs have a large input impedance.
- Ideal for high-speed switching circuits.

***Problem:***

However, running a simulation in Multisim I get the following results:
[image]

According to the [datasheet](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/985102/ETC/BSV81/1), when V<sub>GS</sub> is 5V, then R<sub>DS</sub> should be 50Ω. R<sub>DS</sub> is clearly above 50Ω in the simulation. Is there some misunderstanding from my side?

Comment: "March 1971" on the datasheet ... why choose this specific device?

Comment: Also, why are you biasing a depletion mode MOSFET with a positive gate voltage? Also where did you connect the bulk pin?

Comment: You'll notice the BSV81 has 4 terminals, but in your schematic you only have 3. Do you know how the simulator hooked up the 4th terminal that you didn't tell it how to connect?

Comment: The symbol shows the body connected to source, which is the usual condition (Vbs=0) given in the datasheet. But it would be worth checking that's what the Spice model actually does. (Add or link the model in the question if there's any doubt)

Comment: The transistor is not conducting, this is why all the voltage is applied over it. When the transistor is not conducting, Vrdson is much higher. Like mentioned in the previous comments, you have to figure out why the transistor is not conducting. They give you the answer too.

Comment: I am fairly new to MOSFETs, as we've only covered the basics about it in college.
Andy aka you have pointed me in the right direction. I have done more reading up on depletion mode vs enhancement mode and their related symbols. I ran the simulations in Multisim, and they work as expected.

Answer (score -1):

The transistor, mos and bjt, is a highly non-linear electronic device. A resistor is mostly linear. Apply a voltage across it and you get a current. Increase the voltage by a delta and you get an increase in current proportional to the delta voltage.
For your mos simulation, remove resistor R1 and start with a small VDD, say 1 volt and find IDD. Increase VDD and find IDD again. Repeat to form a table, IDD for each VDD and sketch plot IDD as a function of VDD. You will see a rising IDD at first followed by a slowing of the rise rate and finally a region of 'saturation' where the current rises only slightly as VDD increases. This is the characteristic MOS curve.

Now repeat with a different VGS, say 8 volts. You will get a similar shaped curve but saturating at a larger current level. This shows the gate control of IDS. Try that and post. Rds is the reciprocal of the instantaneous slope along these curves and is a function of Vgs and Vds.

So, Rds depends on the operating point of the transistor. Is it in triode or saturation or in between? For your case, Vds is high so that the device is likely to be in saturation where Rds is relatively high. The device operates more like a current source with a large shunt resistance (Rds) so that the output voltage becomes Vdd-Ids*R1. Ids is limited by Vgs. As you increase Vgs you will get a larger Ids and the Vds will drop. Making Vgs very large will drive the device into triode, Rds gets 'small' and Vds will further decrease.

Comment: This answer does not address the question.

Comment: It's a good answer. Meeth needs to understand how MOS works. It's nothing unusual that Rds is different than expected. When you understand MOS then you understand the situation. Experiments of @Agustin Ochoa will help Meeth to understand MOS operations.